# Big-Oh Comparison (mathematically)

Tags: math, comparison, big-o, probability

I have this exercise to solve:

EX) You have 2 algorithms. The first one is O(n) on best case, and O(n^3) on the worst case, and the another one is O(n^2) on both cases. Suppose that the best case happens 90% of the time. Which one would you choose?

I know that from some n, 90%*O(n) + 10%*O(n^3) > 100%*O(n^2). But, how can I prove that mathematically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough information!  For practical purposes, if you don't have any information about the constant that's implicit in the big-Oh notation, then there's really not much you can say, beyond "there's *some* `N` beyond which it's better to use the `O(n^2)` algorithm".  And that `N` could be beyond any sort of practical limit.

Comment: Question: does "not best case" imply "worst case", or are there cases that are neither "best" nor "worst"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answering.

To compare algorithms we must analyze the 'often case', or 'medium case', if you prefer. So, we can reach formulas for both, that is:

a) 0.9n + 0.1n^3
b) 0.5n^2 + 0.5n^2.

Now we can compare both. If there is any n>0 that 0.9n + 0.1n^3 > n^2, b algorithm is better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To have a basic impression, try solving the equation 0.9*n+0.1*n^3>n^2.

Comment: Can you explain how this is useful?  You're effectively assuming that all of the big-Oh implicit constants are equal.  How would you back up that assumption?

Comment: @MarkDickinson just as you state in your comment on the question, the big O notation does not tell anything about the coefficients (and not even about the orders of magnitude), and the equation I suggested does not perfectly replace the original formula. I think a big O notation is not even correct to use in the original problem, as the actual order of magnitude can be different. As the question is admittedly an exercise, I did not want to give away the solution itself, just wanted to show a direction in which to start to think. I should have posted it as a comment, you are right.

Comment: I agree with everything you say here!  I think it's worth putting some of this information into your answer:  in practice, it may well be that it's reasonable to assume that the big-Oh constants are comparable in magnitude, in which case solving that inequality is helpful.  But it would be good to document that assumption in the answer itself.  It would also be worth examining how the solution to the inequality changes when constants are adjusted, to get some idea of how much those constants matter.